# Connect to MySQL from Amazon VPC

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have two subnets: 1 private , 1 public

The public contains an Ubuntu webserver.
The private contains Redhat enterprise with MySQL only (port 3306, 22 open)

I am able to `ssh` to Ubuntu then from Ubuntu `ssh` to Redhat. But I can't MySQL to Redhat from Ubuntu. It gives me:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.x.x.x.x' (113)
```

This issue started after I created the image of the instance and created it in the VPC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you check iptables on redhat. When I restarted redhat it started iptables and prevented me from accessing mysql.

Comment: its how I fixed the issue. I figured it might help someone else out.